# How to add current date and time in ctrx_sync_on_window in loadrunner?

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I want to add current time and date in ctrx_sync_on_window in loadrunner in below format.
e.g   ctrx_sync_on_window("Transfer Report (07/05/21 11:40:28)", ACTIVATE, 7, 0, 1359, 642, "snapshot33", CTRX_LAST);
Please Suggest

Answer (score 1):

See parameterization.  Covered in classroom training.  Covered in self paced training.   Covered in online documentation.   Your mentor should be assisting you after training.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a parameter (Ctrl+L) with the required format of Date & time (07/05/21 11:40:28 -> dd/mm/YY HH:MM:ss) in the parameter list
- Pass this value in ctrx_sync_on_window which needs to be validated.
- This should resolve the issue.

PS : I do not exactly remember the notation for Date & time. You need to check and edit the same